# jQuery: How to execute clearInterval with functions in a queue()?

Tags: jquery, queue, prototype, extend, clearinterval

I have a bit of code that adds to the jQuery prototype that uses timers. The code executes fine through *queue()* but one, or as i would assume, both timers do not clear. This is specially noticeable with the blink-function i have. The DOM element just keeps blinking.

I know the code as such works because before i implemented the queue() it stopped after 6 "blinks". The code is as follows:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        blink: function(times,delay,name) {
            times = times || 1;
            delay = delay || 1000;
            name = name || "fx";
            return this.queue(name, function() {
                var self = this;
                var counter = 0;
                var timer = setInterval( function() {
                    if($(self).hasClass("hidden")) {
                        $(self).removeClass("hidden");
                        counter++;
                    } else {
                        $(self).addClass("hidden");
                    }
                    if(counter == times) {
                        clearInterval("timer");
                        $(self).dequeue();
                    }
                }, delay);
            });
        },
        pause: function(delay,name) {
            delay = delay || 1000;
            name = name || "fx";
            return this.queue(name, function() {
                var self = this;
                var timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    clearTimeout("timer");
                    $(self).dequeue();
                }, delay);
            });
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

The functions are executed like below where $(this) is the object/element in question:

```
$(this).pause(1000).blink(6,175);
```

The problem as i mentioned is that the functions run in order just fine but the timers never seem to clear. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Thought I'd add another question to the above. You see, i'm still a newbie and have read a lot about function returns but never really understood what was happening with the above *return this.queue( ... )*?

When i call the function with 'pause(1000)' what exactly is returned? Or is 'pause(1000)' replaced somehow with the returning object inside the chain? Thanks again!

Comment: You need to do `clearInterval(timer);` and not `clearInterval("timer");`

Comment: and the same for the timeout...

Comment: Well ok... don't i feel stupid. No matter how much i went through the code i never saw that. >.<

You really need other people to review your programming at times. Thanks guys! ^^